# How to change the default prompt in a singularity container

Tags: shell, command-prompt, singularity-container

I am creating a Singularity image and I want to have a custom bash prompt, just like I can set a bash prompt as a normal user by setting the variable `PS1` in my `~/.bash_profile`.

But, unfortunately, Singularity does something to enforce its own prompt that looks like this: `Singularity>`. This is not a very helpful prompt.

I tried to set PS1 in the definition file like in this example:

```
# File prompt-test1.def
Bootstrap: shub
From: alpine:latest
%environment
export PS1="[my-container]\w\$ "
```

I built and ran that image, but to no avail:

```
sudo singularity build prompt-test.sif prompt-test.def
singularity shell prompt-test.sif
# shows Singularity>
```

Using the `env` command in the shell, I noticed that `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set:

```
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
# PS1="Singularity> "; unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

... so I tried to change that:

```
# File prompt-test2.def
Bootstrap: shub
From: alpine:latest
%environment
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="[my-container]\w\$ "; unset PROMPT_COMMAND'
```

... but the prompt remains unchanged! But now, `PROMPT_COMMAND` inside the container looks like

```
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
# PS1="[my-container]\w\$ "; unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND%%; PROMPT_COMMAND=*}";PS1="Singularity> "
```

**edited to replace with better info**: The problem lies in the order in which the files in `/.singularity.d/env` are sourced. The user-defined environment variables are set in `01-base.sh`, but in `99-base.sh` there is the line

```
PS1="Singularity> "
```

... which overwrites my prompt! Also, the approach using `PROMPT_COMMAND` is thwarted because of some code in `/.singularity.d/actions/shell` or `.../run`.

A workaround would be for the user to use an own `.profile`. But that does not work if the user's home directory is bound to the home inside the container, because the `.profile` inside and outside of the container is the same then. Also, I don't want user intervention just to change a prompt.

How can I get my prompt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the shells run by singularity explicitly don't load any profile or rc files. The prompt, annoying as it is, is there to remind you that you are in an image, not the host OS.

If you want to override that anyway, you need to add an additional file to  `/.singularity.d/env` that will be run after everything else. e.g.,

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: alpine:latest

%post -c /bin/bash
    CUSTOM_ENV=/.singularity.d/env/99-zz_custom_env.sh
    cat >$CUSTOM_ENV <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
PS1="[my_container]\w \$"
EOF
    chmod 755 $CUSTOM_ENV
```

Adding `-c /bin/bash` after `%post` tells singularity to use `/bin/bash` instead of the default `/bin/sh`, necessary for the multiline `cat` step afterwards.

*EDIT:* older versions of singularity used a shebang in the first line for specifying an alternate shell, but has changed to `-c /path/to/shell`.

Comment: I'd like to customize PS1 like this to remind me which container I'm in (something like `[$SINGULARITY_NAME] Singularity> `). Is this answer likely be stable for future versions of singularity?

Comment: When playing with magic files there's always a chance that something may change unexpectedly, but I'd say this is fairly stable. It is worth noting that the files in `/.singularity.d/env` are now _always_ sourced with `/bin/sh` so only variable definitions / exports will be persisted.

Comment: Are there anyway to change the interpreter to `/bin/bash`? This information doesn't seem to be listed in the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use `tmux` inside singularity. It has standard shell with path in prompt.